# How to enforce Trusted Docker base images

Tags: image, docker, security, radix

I've seen quite a few posts relating to Docker security and especially with supply chain attacks in the news recently about limiting your Docker base images to images that you trust.

However, I'm finding it difficult to find information on how to actually do this other than maybe some kinda of Dockerfile parsing.  Perhaps we could inspect an image and find that one of the layers contains a sha256 of a base image we trust.

What about in multistage builds? Whatever image we used to build our package should be trusted as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experiences or tools to help ensure that only images that have been approved can be used as a base image for a final image and in multistage builds as well? Basically any "FROM" should be from an image that we can approve.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable content trust for `docker build` which should verify base image integrity.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/trust_automation/#build-with-content-trust